# Toning down the visual effects on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, effects

I'm on a rather low-end machine (Intel Atom Cherrytrail) and the visual effects of Ubuntu 17.10 are not processed very well. It's so slow that it's often a bit confusing. Is there a way to disable transitions like the apps sliding in from the left bottom corner?

Comment: Even if you reduce visual effects, Gnome is still going to be slow. Try something like Ubuntu Mate or Xubuntu instead.

Comment: @mikewhatever I thought one of the first replies would be along those lines. I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 because it is most compatible with my hardware. I don't mind it being slow and I am prepared to deal with that but the transitions are disturbing and unnecessary.

Comment: @pomsky Thanks! That's a solution indeed. Initially, I wanted to speed up the animations but slowing them down makes it work a lot better.